# How to extract factor scores for each observation in IRT?

Tags: r, item-response-theory

```
library(ltm)
fit <- rasch(LSAT)
factor.scores(fit)
```

This code can generate latent trait scores for response patterns. How can I extract latent trait scores for each observation?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Rach. This Q seems to be *only* about how to get something done in R. If so, it would belong on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), rather than here. If you have a question about any of the related statistical issues, please edit to clarify, if not, flag your Q & we can migrate it for you (*please don't cross-post, though*).

Comment: This could be a great question if you ask not for the code but for the maths and the model behind calculation of factor scores in IRT!

Comment: @ttnphns
may i ask that question? :)

Answer (score 5):

```
fit <- rasch(LSAT)
## Factor scores for all subjects in the
## original dataset LSAT
factor.scores(fit, resp.patterns = LSAT)
```