# theta parameter in R's LTM package

Tags: r, item-response-theory

I am curious whether there is an intuitive way in `ltm` package in `R` to display person's estimated latent trait after fitting the data to an IRT model.

After `install.packages("ltm")`, one can quickly run a two-parameter IRT model with the built-in `WIRS` data, which is a *6-item test with 1,005 persons*:

```
library(ltm)
data <- WIRS
two_pl <- ltm(data ~ z1)
```

The method `coef(two_pl)` displays all the item parameters:

```
          Dffclt    Dscrmn
Item 1  3.4011395 0.1534064
Item 2 -0.9421221 0.3676923
Item 3  0.8093853 1.7179970
Item 4  1.3689278 1.0101043
Item 5  0.4762685 2.0324137
Item 6  1.6804632 1.3745785
```

with `two_pl$coefficients` one can also display `(intercept)` and `z1`. I am not familiar with meaning of the former as there is none in the typical formation of 2PL equation, but `z1` is the discrimination parameter of items.

```
       (Intercept)        z1
Item 1  -0.5217566 0.1534064
Item 2   0.3464111 0.3676923
Item 3  -1.3905215 1.7179970
Item 4  -1.3827598 1.0101043
Item 5  -0.9679746 2.0324137
Item 6  -2.3099285 1.3745785
```

My question: is it possible to find the estimated `theta` parameters for each person in `ltm`?

I have checked the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ltm/ltm.pdf), while they have both `item.fit` and `person.fit`, there is no indication that one can pull out the data of person's latent level trait. In the `WIRS` example, it should be a vector/list with 1,005 elements, but I am still not able to find anything like it after fitting the model.

Comment: This seems to be linked to this question, which is slightly off-topic: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50481/how-to-extract-factor-scores-for-each-observation-in-irt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Theta estimation according to the expected response pattern:

   ```
   Theta <- factor.scores(two_pl)
   ```
2. Theta estimation according to the real data response pattern:

   ```
   Theta <- factor.scores(two_pl, method = "EAP", resp.patterns = data)
   ```

Answer (score 5):

It's the factor.scores function:

```
WIRStheta <- ltm::factor.scores(two_pl)
```

Comment: I see, I was confused by the many different notations. Thanks for the clarification!